# Total number of posts in last year

Tags: statistics, sql

How can i echo total number of posts in last year ? I‚m writing article with stats, and want to get number of posts i published last year.

There is something here, but not for last year http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/08/28/display-total-number-of-posts/ It displays only total number of all posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is modify the SQL query.  Using the code you linked as a base:

```
$numposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND year(post_date) = 2010");
if (0 < $numposts) $numposts = number_format($numposts);
```

The 'AND' I added basically gives you all the posts of 2010.  Change the year accordingly

Comment: *"I hope I can get to the point where I give good answers myself."* Welcome to that point, enjoy the view from here!

Comment: @Jan feels good indeed.

Comment: Thanks. I find out pluging that gives me some good stats for 2010. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/2010-summary/